# QWebView and embedded YouTube player - not working properly

Tags: qt, youtube, embedded-resource, pyqt5, qwebview

My system:

**OS:** Debian Jessie 64bit

**GPU:** ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 (with proprietary video drivers)

I'm working with `PyQt5` and want to embed a `QWebView` with a YouTube tutorial video inside a `QWizardPage`. However what I'm getting is the following is really strange:

- Video doesn't load at all if I use the **embedded** link for the video (that is - the embedded YouTube player) which is basically what I want to use and not load the complete YouTube website
- If I use the normal link (not embedded) I get not image but there is sound
- The playback time is **always** messed up - I get `-Nan:Nan` when I however the player's playback trackbar and `
- In the terminal (where I start my `PyQt5` application from) always gives me the following errors:

  ```
  Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
  Cannot connect to server request channel
  jack server is not running or cannot be started
  ```

Especially the last error really baffles me since yes, there is not `JACK` server running because I don't use `JACK` (I use `PulseAudio` and `ALSA` depending on the case). Does `QWebView` require `JACK` on Linux systems?

Here is a screenshot of my `QWizard` and the respective `QWizardPage`:

[image]

The code I use is as follows (the URL is just an example (video is mine) for the purpose of this post):

```
class CalibrationPageWelcome(QWizardPage):
    '''
    Gives an overviewo of the calibration procedure including some external URLs to tutorials
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CalibrationPageWelcome, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTitle('Calibration Wizard')
        self.setSubTitle('The wizard will guide you through the process of calibrating your camera device.')

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel('''
            Before you continue make sure you are familiar with the process of calibration.
            The video below will give a brief explanation what the calibration process is for 
            and how it will be done using this wizard
        ''')
        label.setWordWrap(True)
        layout.addWidget(label)

        view = QWebView()
        # TODO Add link to tutorial about calibrating a camera using patterns and OpenCV
        view.load(QUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/5sOiGJRyoBI'))
        layout.addWidget(view)

        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the appropriate GStreamer dependencies installed - on Debian Jessie this should be:

`apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-{bad,base,good,ugly}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have those (double-checked to make sure) so the problem doesn't seem to be coming from there.